# jQuery expression in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have tested the following script is working in my PHP page:

```
<script>
  function calculate<?=$performance_item_id;?>(){
    alert('<?=$performance_item_id;?>');
    $.post('complete_calculate.php',{
      tid: document.getElementById('performance_item_id<?=$performance_item_id;?>').value
    },
    function(output){
      $('#complete_percentage<?=$performance_item_id;?>').html(output);
    });
  }
  calculate<?=$performance_item_id;?>()
</script>
<span id='complete_percentage<?=$performance_item_id;?>'></span>
```

First, I would like to change the post value to something like `"$('.complete<?=$performance_item_id;?>').val();"`, that is, not get something from an id field, but gather values from several fields having the same class.

Second, I would like to use a text box to hold the HTML output, while "`<input type = "text" id='complete_percentage<?=$performance_item_id;?>' name = "complete_percentage[]" size = "5" value="0">`" is not working! Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You've included jQuery, but you're only using it for AJAX...

Comment: @Blender: you're saying that like it's bad PS: he also uses it for DOM modifications

Comment: so, am I writing something possible??? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but here are a few points to consider:

1. There's no need to constantly intermingle your PHP with the JavaScript.
   Store the value of `$performance_item_id` in a JavaScript variable, then re-use that.
2. There's no need to declare a function and then immediately call it.
   You can use the `(function(){}())` pattern* to execute your code immediately.
3. Use jQuery's [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) functions to get an array of all the values.

```js
(function () {
    var id = '<?=$performance_item_id;?>';
    alert(id);

    $.post('complete_calculate.php', {   
        tid: $('.complete' + id).map(function(){ return this.value; }).get()
    }, function(output) {
        $('#complete_percentage' + id).html(output);
    }); 
}());
```

<sub>* Called either a **Self Executing Annonymous Function** or an **Immediately Invoked Function Expression**.</sub>

---

After further clarification, it seems you don't need *any* PHP in your JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('[class^=complete_]').keyup(function() {
        $.post('complete_calculate.php', {   
            tid: $('.' + this.className).map(function(){ return this.value; }).get()
        }, function(output) {
            $('#complete_percentage' + this.className.replace('complete', '')).html(output);
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: it works during onload situation! Actually, $('.complete' + id) are textfields for integers that I wish to trigger the function when onchange. How shall I modify it?? Thanks!!

Comment: @Ham - Can you explain in more detail? What do you want to trigger when the `input`s' values changes?

Comment: OK. Initially, there are 3 sets of textfields having class namely complete1, complete1, complete1, complete2, complete2, complete2, complete3, complete3, complete3, and when I input an integer inside 1 of the 9 textfields and keyup, it will trigger the function that you shared. Thanks!

Comment: @Ham - I added some more code to my answer. However, are you sure you want to make an AJAX call after *every* keyup? Why not use `blur`?

Comment: Oh, I found onblur is better! Thanks! Besides, I wish to display the returned value from complete_calculate.php inside a textfield instead of a span, is it possible?? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Joseph, I finally trial the answer!! that is to change html(output) to val(output). Thanks!